# Aggregation not working with monger for mongodb version 3.6

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

Mongo aggregation framework has some [changes in version 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/)  Earlier aggregation queries with monger are not working even when we pass *:cursor {}* as an option. Is there any workaround or do we have to wait for the next monger release?. The error we get is specified below

> MongoCommandException Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }  com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException (ProtocolHelper.java:115)

Answer (score 1):

by OSt advice, I could run [monger aggregation sample](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/aggregation.html) with codes below.

```
(mc/aggregate db coll
    [{"$project" {:subtotal {"$multiply" ["$quantity", "$price"]}
                  :_id "$state"}}]
    :cursor {:batch-size 0})
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to mongo db spec, cursor became a required field in some cases. So you should provide it through monger API. It is not a problem in monger,  it is a breakable change in mongo db API.